# Finding elements from a list included in another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists

```
list_1=['mom','father','daughter','dog','soccer']
list_2=['beautiful mom','father day','snoop dog','Manchester United','Windows Office', 'Snoopy Dog']
```

and I would like to construct a relationship, whether a word from `list_1` is in `list_2`.
For example:

```
mom : ['beautiful mom']
father : ['father day']
daughter : []
dog : ['snoop dog', 'Snoopy Dog']
soccer : []
```

For each element in `list_1` I need to look at `list_2`. If there the element is included, I add it in a list.
I tried as follows:

```
set(list_1).issubset(list_2)
```

looking at subsets; but as I mentioned, my expected output would be something like this (in a pandas dataframe):

```
list_1         Match
mom        ['beautiful mom']
father     ['father day']
daughter   []
dog        ['snoop dog', 'Snoopy Dog']
soccer     []
```

Comment: Seems like you're doing a Term Document Matrix (or TFIDF, or whatever). It's generally better to use matrices than lists. There are [tons of existing solutions on this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Term+Document+Matrix+pandas), please take a look at them.

Comment: Thanks smci. I will have a look at the topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an inverted index mapping individual words to phrases in `list_2`. Then it's just a matter of looking them up from `list_1`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_1=['mom','father','daughter','dog','soccer']
list_2=['beautiful mom','father day','snoop dog','Manchester United','Windows Office', 'Snoopy Dog']

index = defaultdict(list)

for v in list_2:
    for k in v.split():
        index[k.lower()].append(v)

res = {k:index[k.lower()] for k in list_1}
```

`res` will be:

```
{'mom': ['beautiful mom'],
 'father': ['father day'],
 'daughter': [],
 'dog': ['snoop dog', 'Snoopy Dog'],
 'soccer': []}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would scale well for a large number of words and long sentences (e.g. tweets). Would it be better to do something like, each element of list_1 in an element of list_2?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following @TrentonMcKinney. What you are suggesting sound like it would be O(n²) (at best). The above makes the index in O(n) (n being number of total words) and then each lookup is constant time. You would also need to figure out how to prevent things like `mom` mapping to words like `moment` if you don't tokenize it.

Comment: I was just trying to determine, if the phrases in `list_2` were quite large, like an email or tweet. How would `index` scale for creating a `dict` with every word and phrase. I guess that situation probably doesn't make sense in the scope of the OP. Thanks Mark

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I think that's a valid concern with large input. Probably more of a memory concern since the dictionary could potentially get large in exchange for not needing to loop through list_2 multiple times. It seems like a tradeoff between space vs. time complexity.